# How to Pass system property to groovy compiler in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have to use a special system property to configure the groovy compiler in a way that cannot be done with the usual compiler configuration. 
But I have trouble setting the system property.

From command line using **-D** or **-P** obviously does not work. There is the system Property command but trying to use it in

`tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {...}` fails, 
because the method is not known there.

Can any body help on this?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
compileGroovy {
   groovyOptions.fork = true
}
```

[Here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.GroovyCompileOptions.html) are the docs for `GroovyCompileOptions` and for `GroovyCompile` [here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.GroovyCompile.html).

Comment: I guess you mean `compileGroovy {  groovyOptions.fork = false }`. and what if I need it forked?

Comment: `compileGroovy` of course! It's just a sample, pass `fork = true.`

Comment: in case of fork=true a system property provided with -D won't be passed over, which leads back to my original question

Comment: It was just an example of usage of this closure. What property would You like to pass to groovy compiler? How command line that would be executed looks like?

Comment: the property is one I defined for debugging the groovy compiler in a gradle environment. So you can be sure there is nothing in a gradle DSL that will cover it. In non-forked mode it works with `./gradlew -Dgroovy.compile.loaders=true clean test`, but I'd like to have the fork version too

Comment: Ok, so You'd like to know how to pass the property to gradle task as well as how it can be done with fork mode?

Comment: If I would not have to fill at least 5 characters I would now simply have written a "yes". But yes.

Comment: Would be great to have an example to try. On github maybe? But dont't knwo how to do it out of the box.

Comment: If you absolutely need something for testing, you could for example use groovy.target.indy to enable compilation using invokedynamic

Comment: Would like to help you but I'm very busy with MCE conf now. Can't count on me :/